# org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper is missing newXMLReader() method

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

As specified in https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/, I am not seeing  in newXMLReader() method org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper, Just want to cross check if I am missing anything here.

Comment: I've refactored the various internal helper classes and moved the methods to the XMLHelper - I've marked the XMLHelper class as @Internal ... so the API is not regarded stable.

Comment: I'm trying to follow some of the documentation to use the XSSFReader, and the examples all do something like 
    XMLReader sheetParser = XMLHelper.newXMLReader()
What's the alternative now?

Comment: XMLReader sheetParser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();  worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In case other people have this issue and are not clear what to do now that XMLHelper's method are all Internal, this will work:

```
XMLReader sheetParser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
```

I couldn't find it documented anywhere but stumbled upon it.